# Reasoner does not work in protege

Tags: protege4

I am using PROTEGE 4.4. I am trying to run a Reasoner(Pellet/Hermit) on an ontology that I have created. This ontology imports **sweetAll.owl.**  It starts the Reasoner and it begins to classify, but **does not proceed** after some progress. What could be the reason?? There are no error messages thrown. How is my ontology going to work if this reasoner does not execute correctly. Please help.

Comment: You most probably need to add code snippets so people can help you.

Comment: Hi, 
Looks like I had some problem with the Object property hierarchy. I am re-modelling the ontology and checking through reasoning at each step. It works now :) So, the trick is to keep checking the inferences at each step of ontology development !!